# How can I filter from the map in the document?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I filter from the map in the document?

my query function;

```
      ref
        .where('tag_id', isEqualTo: item)
        .where('likes', arrayContains: {
          Get.find<AuthController>().getCurrentUser!.uid: true
        })
        .orderBy('created_date', descending: true)
        .orderBy('like_count', descending: true)
        .orderBy('comment_count', descending: true)
        .limit(max.value)
        .get();
```

I want to filter on 'likes' map. I tried to make an example in the code below, but no data is coming.
map in document

[image: map in document]

returning null

Answer (score 1):

Your `likes` is not an array, so `array-contains` won't work on it.

What you're looking for is :

```
const uid = Get.find<AuthController>().getCurrentUser!.uid;
ref
  .where('tag_id', isEqualTo: item)
  .where('likes.$uid', isEqualTo: true)
```

For more on this dot notation, see the Firebase documentation on [updating fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Comment: Thank you very much.